# What's the difference between getEulerYPR, getEulerZYX and getRPY?

Tags: ros, c++, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,
I noticed `tf::Matrix3x3` provides 3 distinct methods (`getEulerYPR`, `getEulerZYX` and `getRPY`) and they all seem to give the very same results :

The output of the following snippet is given below :

```
   double roll, pitch, yaw;
   tf::Matrix3x3(transform.getRotation()).getRPY(roll, pitch, yaw);
            
   std::cout<<"getRPY():      "<<roll<<" "<<pitch<<" "<<yaw<<"\n";
   tf::Matrix3x3(transform.getRotation()).getEulerYPR(yaw, pitch, roll);
   std::cout<<"getEulerYPR(): "<<roll<<" "<<pitch<<" "<<yaw<<"\n";
   tf::Matrix3x3(transform.getRotation()).getEulerZYX(yaw, pitch, roll);
   std::cout<<"getEulerZYX(): "<<roll<<" "<<pitch<<" "<<yaw<<"\n";
```

outputs:

```
getRPY():      0.000254904 -0.00770209 -0.0312527
getEulerYPR(): 0.000254904 -0.00770209 -0.0312527
getEulerZYX(): 0.000254904 -0.00770209 -0.0312527
```

Why do we have duplicate methods that seem to do exactly one thing? Can somebody please shed some light on this?
Thanks a lot in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381707/what%27s-the-difference-between-geteulerypr,-geteulerzyx-and-getrpy?/) by [Rika](https://answers.ros.org/users/75014/rika/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2021-07-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**attribute**((deprecated))
void getEulerZYX(tfScalar& yaw, tfScalar& pitch, tfScalar& roll, unsigned int solution_number = 1) const
{
getEulerYPR(yaw, pitch, roll, solution_number);
};

```
  void getRPY(tfScalar& roll, tfScalar& pitch, tfScalar& yaw, unsigned int solution_number = 1) const
  {
     getEulerYPR(yaw, pitch, roll, solution_number);
  }
```

[No difference according to the code](https://docs.ros.org/en/kinetic/api/tf/html/c++/Matrix3x3_8h_source.html)

No real cost maintenanceto allow different functions that just have different argument names to the same underlying function.

---

Originally posted by [bob-ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/45543/bob-ros/) with karma: 525 on 2021-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1